# Dynamically change zoom level of QTextEdit to keep all text visible

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am using Qt via PySide6/PyQt to create a `QTextEdit` widget which fills the main window. As it accumulates text from the user, I would like to dynamically zoom out (using `.zoomIn` / `.zoomOut`) to keep all the text visible on screen at once.

I am not quite sure how to go about detecting if the text is overflowing in the text box.

Is there a Signal for this or some other obvious way to detect this that I am not seeing?

Comment: There is no such a signal, as that's not some purpose generally useful for a widget like QTextEdit and, most importantly, "self-scaling" text is something actually difficult (and often unreliable) to achieve. You could achieve some results by checking the document's text layout, but be aware that it's very easy to fall into recursion and performance issues, especially considering that most fonts don't "scale" equally depending on their size: a font with size 20 looks almost **never** as the same font at half the size and zoomed in twice.

Comment: Surely this is doomed to failure, since you'll very quickly reach a point where the text is too small to see (even for normal-sighted people). Imagine what these comments would look like if twice the number of characters were scaled to fit in the same space.